# Does GitLab CI treat Docker entrypoint & cmd differently somehow?

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

I'm getting some unexpected behaviour when trying to run a GitLab CI job inside a custom Docker container. It runs as expected outside GitLab. I don't even know what it is I'm not understanding... perhaps there's something about how GitLab runs docker containers that I'm missing, or how Docker `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` work together, or is it even just a mistake in my shell script?

My custom Docker image is intended to run [Percy](https://percy.io/) CLI commands. It's based on `node:12-slim` and basically just installs Puppeteer and Percy. It sets the `ENTRYPOINT` to a custom shell script:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/local/percy-entrypoint.sh"]
```

but doesn't override the base image `CMD`.

My entrypoint script essentially just checks for a couple of env vars (and chucks out some debug stuff), then runs a "sitemap" function:

```
echo "All args:"
echo "$@"

if [ "$1" = "sitemap" ] ; then
    percy exec -- node /sitemap.js
else
    exec "$@"
fi
```

I'm running it from a GitLab-CI job as:

```
snapshot:
  stage: test
  image: my/percy-buildbox:latest
  script:
    - sitemap
  variables:
    PERCY_TOKEN: ${PERCY_TOKEN}
    SITEMAP_URL: percy-sitemap.xml
```

The output generated by this job is:

```
All args:
sh -c if [ -x /usr/local/bin/bash ]; then
    exec /usr/local/bin/bash 
elif [ -x /usr/bin/bash ]; then
    exec /usr/bin/bash 
elif [ -x /bin/bash ]; then
    exec /bin/bash 
elif [ -x /usr/local/bin/sh ]; then
    exec /usr/local/bin/sh 
elif [ -x /usr/bin/sh ]; then
    exec /usr/bin/sh 
elif [ -x /bin/sh ]; then
    exec /bin/sh 
elif [ -x /busybox/sh ]; then
    exec /busybox/sh 
else
    echo shell not found
    exit 1
fi
$ sitemap
/bin/bash: line 134: sitemap: command not found
```

I don't even... where's all that `if` stuff coming from? What's it doing? Where am I going wrong?